# Resolving conflicts with PyQt new-style signals-slots

Tags: qt, pyqt, signals-slots

`QComboBox` has two signals, both called `currentIndexChanged`; one passes the index of the selected item, and the other passes the text of the selected item. When I connect this signal to my slot, with something like `self.myComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.mySlot)` it gives me an index. Is there a way I can use new-style signals to indicate that I want the text returned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the second example in [connecting signals portion](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signals) of documentation.

In your case it would be:

```
self.myComboBox.currentIndexChanged[QtCore.QString].connect(self.mySlot)
```

or if you are using v2 API for `QString`

```
self.myComboBox.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.mySlot)
```

Answer (score 5):

You must specify the return value within brackets if you want non-default value to be returned

```
self.myComboBox.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.mySlot)

def mySlot(self, item):
    self.currentItem = item
```

see : http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html