# Connecting an overloaded PyQT signal using new-style syntax

Tags: pyqt4, python, signals-slots

I am designing a custom widget which is basically a **QGroupBox** holding a configurable number of **QCheckBox** buttons, where each one of them should control a particular bit in a bitmask represented by a [**QBitArray**](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qbitarray.html). In order to do that, I added the **QCheckBox** instances to a [**QButtonGroup**](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qbuttongroup.html), with each button given an integer ID:

```
    def populate(self, num_bits, parent = None):
        """
        Adds check boxes to the GroupBox according to the bitmask size
        """
        self.bitArray.resize(num_bits)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        for i in range(num_bits):
            cb = QCheckBox()
            cb.setText(QString.number(i))
            self.buttonGroup.addButton(cb, i)
            layout.addWidget(cb)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

Then, each time a user would click on a checkbox contained in *self.buttonGroup*, I'd like *self.bitArray* to be notified so the corresponding bit in the array can be set/unset accordingly. For that I intended to connect **QButtonGroup's** *buttonClicked(int)* signal to **QBitArray's** *toggleBit(int)* method and, to be as pythonic as possible, I wanted to use new-style signals syntax, so I tried this:

```
self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.bitArray.toggleBit)
```

The problem is that *buttonClicked* is an overloaded signal, so there is also the *buttonClicked(QAbstractButton*)* signature. In fact, when the program is executing I get this error when I click a check box:

```
The debugged program raised the exception unhandled TypeError
"QBitArray.toggleBit(int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QCheckBox'"
```

which clearly shows the *toggleBit* method received the *buttonClicked(QAbstractButton*)* signal instead of the *buttonClicked(int)* one.

So, the question is, how can I specify the signal connection, **using new-style syntax**, so that *self.bitArray* receives the *buttonClicked(int)* signal instead of the default overload - *buttonClicked(QAbstractButton*)*?

**EDIT:** The [PyQT's New-style Signal and Slot Support documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator) states you can use *pyqtSlot* decorators to specify which signal you want to connect to a given slot, but that is for a slot you are creating. What to do when the slot is from a "ready made" class? Is the only option subclassing it and then reimplementing the given slot with the right decorator?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While browsing for related questions I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9269089/1007502) to be exactly what I needed. The correct new-style signal syntax for connecting only **QButtonGroup's** *buttonClicked(int)* signal to **QBitArray's** *toggleBit(int)*, ignoring the other overloaded signatures, involves specifying the desired type in brackets, like this:

```
self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.bitArray.toggleBit)
```