# What is the meaning of the brackets in the code line 'combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)' for pyside?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

In a  [pyside tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/widgets2/) I see the following line in the QtGui.QComboBox example:

```
combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)
```

What does the expression `[str]` mean in this context? This is neither explained in the example, not on the [pyside documentation](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QComboBox.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QComboBox.activated). And also from the original [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#activated-2) it is not clear what the expression `[str]` actually means.

I am well aware of indexing lists and dictionaries, but in the given context it seems a class method is indexed.

Comment: And what kind of edit would that be?

Comment: A vote is locked in after a few minutes, and can't be changed unless the question or answer is edited, which is why I requested you make an edit. I've up-voted now and deleted all of my original comments. If you do the same it will clean up the mess I started :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, `activated` is an *overloaded signal*, and `[str]` is indexing to the `str`-typed overload.

The signal is *overloaded* for the same reason a function is considered overloaded in C++: There are two functions with the same name, taking different parameters:

```
void QComboBox::activated ( int index ) [signal]
void QComboBox::activated ( const QString & text ) [signal]
```

Python doesn't have the strongly-typed function overloading that C++ has. So instead, PyQt handles this by having a dictionary of slots to which you can connect. The key to this dictionary is the `type` of the argument your handle will accept.

This example on the page that [wastl linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23847297/119527) describes it well:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QComboBox

class Bar(QComboBox):

    def connect_activated(self):
        # The PyQt4 documentation will define what the default overload is.
        # In this case it is the overload with the single integer argument.
        self.activated.connect(self.handle_int)

        # For non-default overloads we have to specify which we want to
        # connect.  In this case the one with the single string argument.
        # (Note that we could also explicitly specify the default if we
        # wanted to.)
        self.activated[str].connect(self.handle_string)

    def handle_int(self, index):
        print "activated signal passed integer", index

    def handle_string(self, text):
        print "activated signal passed QString", text
```

**Further Reading:**

- [PyQt and Signal Overloads](http://pysnippet.blogspot.com/2010/09/pyqt-and-signal-overloads.html) (Blogspot)
- [Connecting an overloaded PyQT signal using new-style syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173028/connecting-an-overloaded-pyqt-signal-using-new-style-syntax) (Stack Overflow)

Comment: Interesting, I did not know python had `overloaded signal` types. How to you define such kind of methods in the first place?

Comment: @Alex It's not Python - It's just how PyQt implements it. Check out that linked blog post.

Comment: Well, is IS python. And I am interested not only how I can use it, but how it is created in python. Is it then a python extension of some sort? Can this `signal overload` be done in pure python (without `pside`)?

Comment: PyQt is open source. You could [download the source code](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) to see how they implement it. Like I mentioned though, it's probably a `dict` where they keys are `type`s (which is why you pass the `str` type to indicate a handler that accepts a string argument.)

Comment: This will probably be difficult to find as PyQt uses [SIP](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/introduction.html) to automatically generate the Python bindings to Qt. In `sip/QtGui/qcombobox.sip` we see the two different `activated` signals listed. SIP probably generates the dictionary of signals after detecting the two overloads. You could of course really dig in and look at the [SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/download) source code as well.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer.

Answer (score 0):

[str] defines that the argument passed to your handler will be string
Take a look here: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signals